# How to overwrite an existing .txt file

Tags: java, file

I have an application that creates a .txt file. I want to overwrite it. This is my function:

```
try{
    String test = "Test string !";
    File file = new File("src\\homeautomation\\data\\RoomData.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }else{

    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(test);
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What should I put in the else clause, if the file exists, so it can be overwritten?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwriting txt file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729625/overwriting-txt-file-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do anything particular in the else clause. You can actually open a file with a `Writer` with two different modes :

- default mode, which overwrites the whole file
- append mode (specified in the constructor by a boolean set to `true`) which appends the new data to the existing one

Comment: "You don't need to do anything particular in the else clause"... Actually you mean, he shouldn't have an if clause too. Just trying to come up with some smart comment myself :)

Comment: I thought that `createNewFile` would create all the non-existing parent directories of the file, but after taking a look at the doc, it doesn't (`File.mkdirs()` do). So yes, the if clause is unnecessary here

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do anything, the default behavior is to overwrite.

No clue why I was downvoted, seriously... this code will always overwrite the file

```
try{
        String test = "Test string !";
        File file = new File("output.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(test);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `file.delete()` in your else block. That should delete the file, if that's what you want.

Comment: He does not want to delete the file, he wants to overwrite it. He's talking about deletion because he does not know how a `Writer` works and think he need to delete the file to overwrite it

Comment: He can delete it, then do the same as in the case where it doesn't exist. That's why I put "if that's what you want", I wasn't quite sure what he wants.

Comment: Then why even deleting it, since he will obtain the same result without doing so ?

Comment: @Dici Right, that's smart indeed. I wouldn't have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```

Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

The Below one line code will help us to make the file empty.

```
FileUtils.write(new File("/your/file/path"), "")
```

The Below  code will help us to delete the file .

```
try{

            File file = new File("src\\homeautomation\\data\\RoomData.txt");

            if(file.delete()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```